# Does Software Updater update apps installed by Software Center

Tags: software-center, update-manager

I just want to know if I could install a bunch of apps through the Software Center and not have to add individual repositories to update every single app.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- If the application was installed originally from Software Center, then yes you have it in repositories already (although some apps might have other updated version outside ubuntu official repositories).
- If an application was installed by a method other than Software Center, then maybe or maybe not you have its repository automatically added during installation (you need to check software sources or sources.list file for that).
- Other application - MySQL workbench for example, have an in app tool to check for an update, and might direct you directly to update process.

Answer (score 1):

If the repositories contains the update for a particular package then software updater updates that package.

Installing package via software-center does the same function as installing package via `apt-get`.

Yes, software updater updates packages installed via software-center only if the corresponding package had an update in enabled repositories.

Comment: i know how the repositories work, im asking about the software center